# Not erroring only showing white screen

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, localhost

I'm trying to work locally on my mac with the Mamp software and have a fresh install of Codeigniter set up in a subdirectory of my sites folder and when I try and load my Home controller I'm not getting any errors or have anything being displayed on the screen and I'm trying to find out why that could be.

```
- Documents
    -Sites
        -mysite
            -application
                -controllers
                    home.php
```

I'm started the apache and mysql servers and went to `http://localhost/mysite/` . The default controller that I have set up in the routes is home and I'm getting a white screen. This is the following code I have inside the home controller.

```
<?php

class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        public $data = array();
        echo 'this is the index function';
        //$this->load->view('homepage', $data, TRUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your Apache error log.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jessica. Where is this located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't load a helper/controller/library but you use some of the functions in it, you will get a white screen too.

That is the first thing I check when I get white screens.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you’re using mysqli—make sure it’s installed on the machine. CI does not spit out an error, you get just a blank page no source, no nothing.
2. In your index.php file, if error reporting is set to E_ALL, make sure your logs folder is writeable.
3. This happened a while ago, but running PHP in CGI mode was causing the same blank page error.

Hope that helps others out there

Reference taken from Codeigniter's forum [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/84634/) and [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/110839/) is another one talking about the blank page issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `error_reporting(-1)`

See: [php.net/.../function.error-reporting.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Answer (score 1):

I use the same setup. Your apache/php/mysql errors are located in /Applications/Mamp/logs folder. You have a php error somewhere. I get this a lot. You have to make sure all your paths are correct etc or this will happen.